# mySQL if same row exists do update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table with 6 columns, i want my insert command to do update if 4 of them are the same.
this is how the table look like for an example

```
id  customer_id  sensor_id  user_unique_id        date        timestamps              
------  -----------  ---------  -----------------  ----------  -----------------------

 1           21         19  56346345645645654  2013-07-12  1373623091             
 2           21         18  34676546754756765  2013-07-12  1373623091             
 3           21         18  56754754754675755  2013-07-12  1373623047             
 4           21         18  54674567546754757  2013-07-12  1373623036,1373623037             
 5           21         18  54675647567547547  2013-07-12  1373623035
```

if the i try to insert

```
INSERT INTO table ('customer_id`,`sensor_is`,`user_unique_id`,`date`,`timestamps`)
VALUES ('21','19','56346345645645654','2013-07-12','1373623100')
```

i want the code to do update like the following :

```
UPDATE table SET `timestemps`=`timestemps`+','+VALUES(timestemps)
WHERE customer_id = VALUES(customer_id)
AND sensor_is = VALUES(sensor_is)
AND user_unique_id = VALUES(user_unique_id)
AND date = VALUES(date)
```

i have tried to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but i cant make all the columns unique..
help me please :(

Comment: you don't need to make the columns unique, but **index** that consists of these 4 fields

Comment: storing comma-separated data in a single field is a very BAD idea

Comment: i know its a bad idea but this way saves me allot of run time,
about the index, how do i index them together, and how do i execute this kind of command?

Comment: it doesn't save you a lot of time but makes you in a fix which will cost you a REAL lot of time to solve in a future